# Почему сайт на хостинге Github не работает

Tags: github, хостинг, github-pages

Загрузил на хостинг GitHub сайт. Когда ввожу сылку на сайт в поисковике GitHub выдает Eror 404 сайт не найден. Что делать?

Comment: ссылку можно увидеть?

Comment: Вы всё сделали именно так? https://pages.github.com/

Comment: а у меня просто при переходе на созданный "сайт" отображается название как бы этого сайта (репозитория), как будто хитхаб не видит файлов моего сайта, хотя везде стоит ветка master, в чем может быть неточность?